# Remove query string from url without refreshing the page?

Tags: url, refresh

There is a page needs query string to trigger a function:

`http://www.example.com/index.html?triggerfunc`

After the function is performed, is it possible to remove the query string (make the url like the following one) without refreshing the page?

`http://www.example.com/index.html`

Comment: Do you require query string. Even values can be posted via POST method while submitting the form. In this case the URL will not change.

Comment: Yes, query string is required. The query string was brought to the current page by clicking anchor elements in another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,the url is controlled by browser,the browser have to reload when you changed the url.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @Vito Van is right. The browser controls the URL. You can resubmit the code twice to remove the query string while retaining the final response.